# Should this holdem hand result in a split pot?

Tags: texas-hold-em, poker-strategy, learning, hand, drawing

In Holdem poker, on the board are 2 Kings /6/4/2. There are 2 players in the hand, one calling the other. One man has a king and a queen. The other has a king an a 9. My question is whether this a split pot?

Comment: No. Poker hands have 5 cards. First player's hand is KKKQ6, which beats second player's hand of KKK96.

Answer (score 6):

No.  The player with KQ would win the whole pot.  The winner of the pot is the player who can make the best 5-card hand from the 7 possible cards -- 5 board cards plus their two hole cards.

Player 1 has KQ, so his 7 cards are KKKQ642.  Ignoring suits, the best possible hand here is KKKQ6, or trip kings with a queen kicker.

Player 2 has K9, so his 7 cards are KKK9642.  Ignoring suits, the best possible hand here is KKK96, or trip kings with a 9 kicker.

For both players, their second card plays as part of their best possible hand, so in this case the player with the KQ will win the whole pot.

If the board had instead come out something like KK662, with the sixes also paired, it would be a split pot. In that case, the best 5-card hand for both players would be KKK66, or kings full of sixes. The second hole card for each player would be irrelevant, and the players would both tie for the best hand and the pot would be split.